# Программа/веб-сервис, генерирующие хеш текстовых данных по ГОСТ Р 34.11-2012

Tags: xml, хеширование, гост

В своём сервисе формируют xml, и часть xml подписываю подписью. Но подпись не проходит у принимающей стороны. Думаю на хеш. Но не нашёл, как проверить его правильность. Может кто знает, онлайн-сервис для формирования хеша или его проверки? Или какую-то оффлайновую программу. Нужно сформировать хэш для части xml.

Пробовал программу cpverify.exe (сохранял подписываему часть xml в отдельный файл), но хеш, получаемый этой программой, не совпадает с хешами, которые мне даны в примерах принимающей стороны.
Также другой программист нашей фирмы, который тоже работал с подписыванием, говорит, что у него эта программа никогда не выдавала правильный хэш.

Comment: Вы можете найти исходники хеш-функции на удобном для вас языке. В меня есть своя имплементация на c#

Comment: @Zergatul А в скомпилированном виде что-нибудь есть? Ваша имплементация правильно хэш считает? Как проверяли?

Comment: В скомпилированном виде нет. Хеш считает правильно, есть тесты. Сама хеш функция: https://github.com/Zergatul/ZergatulLib/blob/master/Zergatul/Cryptography/Hash/Streebog.cs и тесты: https://github.com/Zergatul/ZergatulLib/blob/master/Zergatul.Cryptography.Tests/Hash/StreebogTests.cs